# Incrementing different variables via the ternary operator in a for loop

Tags: python, increment, ternary

I'm trying to add to a different variable  based on a test, within my for loop:

```
for i in range(alist.__len__()):
        if alist[i] is not blist[i]:
            ascore +=1 if alist[i] > blist[i] else bscore+=1
    print(ascore,bscore)
```

This code does not work. What I understand is happening is that the if condition is not applying to the whole assignment (we increment ascore if condition), it is instead applying to my value 1 (we increment ascore by 1 if condition). I would prefer functionality similar to the first. Anything I can do here? I understand just breaking it down into if elsif could easily solve this particular problem, but I ma more interested in the way the ternary operator (one line conditionals) work in python. Thankyou!

Comment: Assignments aren't expressions in Python (unlike C/C++) so you can't use the ternary operator here (which only works with expressions).

Answer (score 7):

No. Unfortunately, you cannot use the ternary operator. As the name implies, it's an *operator*, so both the left hand and right hand sides must be expressions. However, unlike many other languages, [Python assignments are *statements*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt), thus they cannot be used in the place of an expression.

The solution, as you correctly noted, is to use a normal conditional statement:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
        if alist[i] is not blist[i]:
            if alist[i] > blist[i]:
                ascore +=1 
            else:
                bscore +=1
    print(ascore, bscore)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not insist on using augmented assignmeng, you can do it like this:

```
ascore, bscore = (ascore + 1, bscore) if alist[i] > blist[i] else (ascore, bscore + 1)
```

Thanks to ShadowRanger for pointing my mistake (I missed the parentheses).

Comment: Your operator precedence is wrong. You just tried to assign a three-`tuple` to two elements; guaranteed `ValueError`. You wanted: `ascore, bscore = (ascore+1, bscore) if alist[i] > blist[i] else (ascore, bscore+1)`, but you effectively wrote: `ascore, bscore = ascore+1, (bscore if alist[i] > blist[i] else ascore), bscore+1`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increment only two variables - you could do it via dictionary, with the following code:

```
scores = {
    True: 0,   # ascore
    False: 0   # bscore
}

for i in range(len(alist)):
    if alist[i] is not blist[i]:
        scores[alist[i] > blist[i]] += 1

print(scores)
```

Or same, but more clear:

```
scores = {
    'ascore': 0,
    'bscore': 0
}

for i in range(len(alist)):
    if alist[i] is not blist[i]:
        scores['ascore' if alist[i] > blist[i] else 'bscore'] += 1

print(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also make sure you use != and normal if statements

```
for i in range(len(alist)):
    if alist[i]!=blist[i]:
        if alist[i]>blist[i]:
            ascore+=1
        else:
            bscore+=1
    print(ascore,bscore)
```

Comment: `is` will return True if two variables point to the same object, `==` if the objects referred to by the variables are equal. This operators have different purposes

Answer (score 0):

Following is a simple way to increment one of the selected using ternary operator.

Assign the variable to increment using the ternary operator to the sore variable, and increment the score variable.

```
score = ascore  if alist[i] > blist[i] else bscore 
score +=1
```